# Firebase authentication with custom token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I have a firebase project which Im trying to authenticate from my rails server creating a custom token with the library ruby-jwt as it says on the docs, but i keep getting the same error:

> auth/invalid-custom-token, The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.

The `credentials.json` is from the service account I made in google console, uid is sent from the front end to the api.

```
def generate_auth_token(uid)
  now_seconds = Time.now.to_i
  credentials = JSON.parse(File.read("credentials.json"))
  private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new credentials["private_key"]
  payload = {
      :iss => credentials["client_email"],
      :sub => credentials["client_email"],
      :aud => 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit',
      :iat => now_seconds,
      :exp => now_seconds+(60*60), # Maximum expiration time is one hour
      :uid => uid.to_s,
      :claims => {:premium_account => true}
    }
  JWT.encode(payload, private_key, 'RS256')
end
```

it looks like this in jwt.io

```
{
  "iss": "defered@defered.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub": "defered@defered.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "aud": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
  "iat": 1486824545,
  "exp": 1486828145,
  "uid": "4",
  "claims": {
     "premium_account": true
   }
}
```

Comment: Please, take a look at my [firebase_id_token](https://github.com/fschuindt/firebase_id_token) gem. It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better way to authenticate, I'm just sending the token that firebase gives you and verifying it on rails with the information I need and that's it.

Comment: Hey, How were you able to verify it in rails ?

Comment: @MohamedALOUANE i send the already logged in user token to my api then i decoded the token with my personal key then check wich user was by looking in the database

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the accepted answer found a way to link authentication from Firebase to Rails, but the original question seems to be asking how to link Rails authentication to Firebase (which is what I was trying to do).

To keep your authentication logic in Rails (ex: from Devise) and share it with Firebase, first get a Firebase server key as a `.json` file from your [Service Accounts](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) page in your project's settings.

You'll only need the `private_key` and `client_id` from this file, which I recommend storing as environment variables so they're not potentially leaked in source code.

Next, make a Plain ol' Ruby object (PORO) that will take in a `User` and spit out a JSON Web Token (JWT) that Firebase can understand:

```rb
class FirebaseToken
  def self.create_from_user(user)
    service_account_email = ENV["FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL"]
    private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new ENV["FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY"]

    claims = {
      isCool: "oh yeah"
    }

    now_seconds = Time.now.to_i
    payload = {
      iss: service_account_email,
      sub: service_account_email,
      aud: "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
      iat: now_seconds,
      exp: now_seconds + (60*60), # Maximum expiration time is one hour
      uid: user.id,
      # a hash to pass to the client as JSON
      claims: claims
    }
    JWT.encode payload, private_key, "RS256"
  end
end
```

Now send this JWT to authenticated users through javascript in your application layout:

```rb
window.firebaseJWT = "#{FirebaseToken.create_from_user(current_user)}";
```

In your frontend code, you can now use this token to authenticate users:

```js
firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithCustomToken(window.firebaseJWT)
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Remember to sign them out of firebase when they sign out of your application:

```js
firebase
  .auth()
  .signOut()
  .then(() => {
    // Sign-out successful.
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Somehow I overlooked that "exp" is a *different time*, not a _difference_ in time. I had "exp: 3600" until I saw: `now_seconds + 60*60`

Comment: @cgenko do you know what data is stored in Firebase? I'm trying to understand what would be stored, and how I could use that data to authorize certain paths in Firebase's realtime database. For example, I want a user with id: 3 to be able to read/write in the path: /3/my_data

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure I understand your question, and I think it's out of scope for this answer. Try making a new question!

Comment: @cgenco I'm more just curious if `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(window.firebaseJWT)` stores any data in firebase. I suppose not, if all we're sending it is the jwt, a user.id, and a set of claims.

Comment: @Matt ahh I think I see what you're saying. I believe signing in users via. any method creates a new user in the Authentication tab but doesn't by default create any data in Firestore. You can set up firebase cloud functions to write data to Firestore triggered by user auth events though.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your secret key is wrapped in double quotes and not single as they contain '\n' escape sequences. An auth/invalid-custom-token error is thrown if the secret key is not as specified in the documentation.